# Windows partition manager from command line

Tags: windows, command-line, partitioning

Is there a tool that can be used to partition a disk (SD card in particular) from the command line? The purpose of this is for batch processing and customized GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt it will work on an SD card, but here is the command: diskpart

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415

Answer (score 1):

KCotreau is right. You can use DiskPart, which is more powerful as a graphical disk management tool.

But there is a problem **for some** USB sticks and SD cards: They usually don't have a [Master Boot Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) (MBR).

In such case you have to delete the existing partition and create a MBR. After this, you can create more than one partitions. But sometimes you have to assign drive letter manually, because Windows recognizes just the first partition.

BTW: A advantage of an existing MBR is, that you can boot from such a media.

Comment: You can _create_ more than one volume on the disc, but [Microsoft's tools themselves won't enable you do so](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/254109) and [Microsoft's operating systems won't like you for doing it](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776032%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an unusual solution, but you could just boot Linux (even off an SD card!) and use the excellent cfdisk. Or fdisk.